# Dynamic component used in render is getting called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a sample test app as below

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const SampleBtn = (props) => {
      console.log('button rendered');
      return <button>test</button>;
    };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <SampleBtn />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I run the above app, `console.log('Button rendered')` is called twice. I tried to remove `<React.StrictMode> also`, it is called twice and sometimes it multiplies. How to resolve this and can I know the reason behind this?

I have used HTML button and create a stackblitz code as below, even then I am seeing the logging twice. Please see the url below
https://react-xd9pzh.stackblitz.io

Comment: If strict mode is off, then the only reason rendering will happen is if something somewhere sets state (or if you refresh the page). The code you showed doesn't have any instances of setting state, so it's probably in some code you didn't show us.

Comment: No, this is all I have used in test app, do you think it is having a problem with the button component I used?

Comment: Could be; that's indeed a piece of code that you didn't show us. I looked up that library (react-button), but can't find their source code.

Comment: @NicholasTower, I tried to replicate the issue, please check the stackblitz url

Comment: That stackblitz is using strict mode, which is why it renders twice (btw, here's the editor link, which is more useful: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xd9pzh)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a render method to the class and move the CustomButton outside the class, a working code will help you to find the issue.

Edit: first code example was unclear to me, like others said, probably it's StrictMode. Keep in mind that it will run only in the development environment. For a quick check on your local machine, for example, if you're using create-react-app you can simply run the build command and then serve the app in your browser to verify if you get a double console.log with the prod build.

Comment: please check the working code url

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).